# Utilizing Materialize library in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm having issues utilizing the materialize library within my chrome extension to display a custom modal when a button is clicked. I've already written code (**in my content script**) to inject a button to the existing web page. In my dialog.html, I have the HTML for my modal (using [this](https://materializecss.com/modals.html) template from materialize-css). Now, I'm trying to call `$('.modal').modal('open');` inside a function that is called when the button is clicked (I've verified that the onclick is working fine, since console.log() works inside of this function.

However, when I try to run `$('.modal').modal('open');`, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`. (I've also tried running `$('.modal').modal();` and the other implementations I found on stackoverflow, but to no avail.

My manifest.json looks like:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "MyChromeExtension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://www.messenger.com/*"],
            "css": ["/thirdParty/materialize.css"],
            "js": ["/thirdParty/jquery.min.js","/thirdParty/materialize.js", "content-final.js"]

        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["/thirdParty/bootstrap.min.css", "/thirdParty/jquery.min.js", "/thirdParty/bootstrap.min.js", "dialog.html", "/thirdParty/materialize.css", "/thirdParty/materialize.js"],
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],
    
    "background": {
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; object-src 'self'"

}
```

I've saved local copies of my jquery, bootstrap, and materialize files inside my folder thirdParty, but for some reason my code doesn't work. I've also tried installing all of these frameworks via npm and using [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) to combine them into my content-final.js, but this doesn't work either.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Sounds like you run the scripts in web_accessible_resources via DOM `script` element in which case they execute in the page context, not in the isolated world of the content scripts. When using such complex modifications to the page it's best to isolate everything inside an iframe pointing to an html file inside your extension. Within this iframe you'll be able to load all resources normally as you would do in any other html page.

Comment: @wOxxOm So in the content script, if I load my dialog.html file by injecting an iframe into the web page, rather than directly like this: ```$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/dialog.html'), function(data){$($.parseHTML(data)).appendTo('body'); });
```I'll be able to just include the materialize js and css files with <script> and <style> tags inside dialog.html?

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting in the comments, can't seem to get multi-line code blocks. Let me know if you'd like me to edit my original post with this

Comment: Yes. I don't understand why you need to confirm though. Just do it (tm) :-).